# Change button background color using swift language

Tags: ios, iphone, colors, uibutton, swift

I am new to the swift language. Can someone tell me how to change the background color of a button using the swift language?

Answer (score 79):

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

Or any other color: `red`, `green`, `yellow` ,etc.

Another option is RGBA color:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 1.0, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: My related question is: the color fills the button's bounding box--- how do you only fill the shape of the button (i.e., the standard system button that has rounded corners)?

Comment: Bear in mind, yourButton.setBackgroundColor(...) is something different. Use this answer.

Answer (score 34):

Try this, you need to add the `255` like so:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 250/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: not quite correct, you need a value between 0.0 and 1.0. So either you use such values or write `115/255`

Comment: thanks, dividing by 255 fixed my error in Swift4.  sender.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 3/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)

Answer (score 13):

Update for xcode 8 and swift 3, specify common colors like:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

the `Color()` has been removed.

Comment: Even better: `button.backgroundColor = .blue` (because the compiler knows that `.backgroundColor` is a UIColor).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set backgroundColor of button programmatically then this code will surly help you

**Swift 3 and Swift 4**

```
self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

**Using RGB**

```
self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 250/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 0.5)
```

or you can use float values

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 1.0, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.5)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4,5 Add background color using number of ways.**

1.Set button Color with below code

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue 
**OR**
button.backgroundColor = .blue
```

2.Using RGB color: red, green, yellow ,etc.

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

3.Using 255 like below

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 203/255, green: 95/255, blue: 173/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

4.Using UIColor Extension like below

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
        scanner.scanLocation = 0
        
        var rgbColorValue: UInt64 = 0
        
        scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbColorValue)
        
        let r = (rgbColorValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
        let g = (rgbColorValue & 0xff00) >> 8
        let b = rgbColorValue & 0xff
        
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat(r) / 0xff,
            green: CGFloat(g) / 0xff,
            blue: CGFloat(b) / 0xff, alpha: 1
        )
    }
}
```

How to use

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex:"FFFFFF")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background color of a button using the getRed function.
Let's assume you have:

1. A UIButton called button, and
2. You want to change button's background color to some known RBG value

Then, place the following code in the function where you want to change the background color of your UIButton

```
var r:CGFloat = 0
var g:CGFloat = 0
var b:CGFloat = 0
var a:CGFloat = 0

// This will be some red-ish color
let color = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 16.0/255.0, blue: 46.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) 

if color.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a){
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is the most stupid thing I've heard in a while. Just use `button.backgroundColor = color`.

Answer (score 0):

U can also play around the tintcolor and button image to indirectly change the color.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Swift-5 update*/

let tempBtn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 20, width: 40, height: 40))       
tempBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

To change your background color of the botton use:

> `yourBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black`

if you are using `storyBoard` make sure you have connected your `storyBoard` with your `viewController` and also that your items are linked.

if you don´t know how to do this check the next link:

[How to connect ViewController.swift to ViewController in Storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311000/how-to-connect-viewcontroller-swift-to-viewcontroller-in-storyboard/64246814#64246814)

Answer (score -1):

## Swift 3

#### Color With RGB

```
btnLogin.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: (100/255), green: (150/255), blue: (200/255), alpha: 1)
```

#### Using Native color

```
btnLogin.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4:**

> You can easily use hex code:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#ff259F6C")

self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(hexString: "#08259F6C").cgColor
```

> Extension for hex color code

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hexString: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        let hexString: String = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexString)
        if (hexString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            scanner.scanLocation = 1
        }
        var color: UInt32 = 0
        scanner.scanHexInt32(&color)
        let mask = 0x000000FF
        let r = Int(color >> 16) & mask
        let g = Int(color >> 8) & mask
        let b = Int(color) & mask
        let red   = CGFloat(r) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat(g) / 255.0
        let blue  = CGFloat(b) / 255.0
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }
    func toHexString() -> String {
        var r:CGFloat = 0
        var g:CGFloat = 0
        var b:CGFloat = 0
        var a:CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        let rgb:Int = (Int)(r*255)<<16 | (Int)(g*255)<<8 | (Int)(b*255)<<0
        return String(format:"#%06x", rgb)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After you connect the UIButton that you want to change its background as an OUtlet to your ViewController.swift file you can use the following:

```
 yourUIButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```