# customized UIButton stays selected and changes color

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is there a way to change the color of a customized UIButton when clicked and let it stay the same until clicked again? Currently I overrode drawRect to create the customized button but don't know where to go from there.

EDIT:

```
class DayButtons: UIButton {

    var isPressed: Bool = false

    var color = UIColor.whiteColor()

        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let cornerR = CGFloat(5)       
        var path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerR)
        color.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you're setting the button color, but the code to change the color of the button will look something like this:

```
yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() // this would make the button color blue.
```

You could set the button color programmatically in `viewDidLoad` and change it when your `IBAction` is called. For example, you could add this line in your `IBAction`:

```
yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

You may find this post helpful:

[Change button background color using swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427284/change-button-background-color-using-swift-language)

## Update

Without seeing the code, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You can change the fill of the rect with this code:
`UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()`.

You could redraw the rect when your button is clicked and tie the color to a `Bool`. Something like this would go inside the `IBAction` tied to your button to toggle the state:

```
if self.myCondition == true { 
    self.myCondition = false
    } else { 
    self.myCondition = true
}
```

Inside the code you're using to create your rect, you could do something like this:

```
if self.myCondition == true { 
    UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
    } else { 
    UIColor.redColor().setFill()
}
```

Comment: yea but i'm changing the customized button, instead of the button frame background color, so I was thinking maybe I could redraw the button when clicked.

Comment: Are you creating the button in Interface Builder or programmatically? What aspect of the button do you wish to change?

Comment: programmatically, I basically drew a ovalRect in drawRect and I only want to change the color of that ovalRect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just added the code for my UIButton subclass. I'm a bit confused about how to call `drawRect` when I press these buttons, because every time I press them they need to be redrawn.