# how to change cell background colour on selected item in UICollectionView and change other Cell colour to default in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new in swift and I am trying to change cell background colour of UICollectionView but its not working my code is like this in cellForItemAt

```
if(cell.isSelected){
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }else{
       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
 }
```

Is there is any way to change only selected cell colour to green and other cell to clear
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You cannot test for selected in cellForItem. You set the backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView for all cells.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620138-selectedbackgroundview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change button background color using swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427284/change-button-background-color-using-swift-language)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a variable inside the vc

```
var currentSelected:Int?
```

then inside `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.backgroundColor = currentSelected == indexPath.row ? UIColor.green : UIColor.clear
```

finally `didSelectItemAt`

```
currentSelected = indexPath.row
collectionView.reloadData()
```

> Don't depend on `isSelected` as cells are dequeued and when you scroll you'll get unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's explanation about cell's backgroungView and selected backgroundView [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/changing_the_appearance_of_selected_and_highlighted_cells) you should change those parameters at the cell class itself and the UICollectionView will know to manage it automatically when the cell is highlighted or selected:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()

  let redView = UIView(frame: bounds)
  redView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
  self.backgroundView = redView

  let blueView = UIView(frame: bounds)
  blueView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
  self.selectedBackgroundView = blueView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Selected in your collection cell....

```
class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var tagTitle: UILabel!
        
        override var isSelected: Bool {
            didSet {
                contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .red : .white
            }
        }
        
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            
        }
    }
```