# How to change the collor of a button once timer runs out?

Tags: ios, swift

*Here is the code that I am using, at the bottom of the code is my timer it is a timer counting up and once it hits 60 minutes I would like for a button to turn red.*

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    @IBAction func btnPressed1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    sender.backgroundColor  = sender.backgroundColor == UIColor.red ? UIColor.black : UIColor.red
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar1: UIProgressView!
    
           
     let start = 5
    var timer = Timer()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    var totalTime = 0
    var secondsPassed = 0
    
    @IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
   
        let startB = sender.titleLabel?.text
        totalTime = start
        
        progressBar1.progress = 0.0
        secondsPassed = 0
        titleLabel.text = "coffee timer"
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if secondsPassed < totalTime {
            secondsPassed += 1
            progressBar1.progress = Float(secondsPassed) / Float(totalTime)
            print(Float(secondsPassed) / Float(totalTime))
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            titleLabel.text = "check coffee"
            
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "alarm_sound", withExtension: "mp3")
            player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
            player.play()
        }
    
    }
}
```

I need the button to turn the color red after my timer ends and if possible when the button is pressed have the color turn back to black.

Comment: You probably want another [`@IBOutlet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ConnectingObjectstoCode.html) for your button so you can change its color.

Comment: where would I put that button and what code would I use to change the color?

Comment: See: https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2016/3/1/60-how-to-create-outlets-and-actions-in-xcode-using-swift & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427284/change-button-background-color-using-swift-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `IBOutlet` to the button, and then use that outlet to update the button in your `updateTimer` routine.

An alternative to adding an `IBOutlet` to the button is to pass the button as the `userInfo:` parameter of the `Timer`.

You can pass anything you want as the `userInfo:` and right now you're just passing `nil`.  If you change `nil` to `sender`, then the button will be passed along to the `Timer`.

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self,
    selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: sender,
    repeats: true)
```

Then, add the `Timer` parameter to `updateTimer`:

```
@objc func updateTimer(t: Timer) {
    if let button = t.userInfo as? UIButton {
        button.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Making use of `userInfo` makes even better sense if you have multiple buttons that share the same `updateTimer` code.  By creating a structure to hold the `secondsPassed` and `button` and passing that structure as `userInfo:`, you could have multiple buttons using multiple timers at the same time and each `Timer` would know which button it was assigned to.