# How to change background color of UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to change the color of UIbuttons but problem is that I have tried changing color in

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

it is not doing anything but on the same time some other buttons are changing colors on this method. I am really confused about this behaviour that some buttons are changing color on same method others don't.

I've also tried @IBOutlet method and it also didn't worked

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```

and then change the color of button in method

```
button.backgroundColor = .red
```

Even setting text or color of the in viewDidLoad not working. It is showing the same button as it is designed in storyboard

Comment: You must declare the button as `IBOulet` and set [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24427334/5941807) as action

Comment: yeah I have declared the @IBOutlet as well and tried to change the backgroud color as well but didn't work

Comment: Check link connection in storyboard for `IBOutlet` and `Action` [the basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVqdylyDSao)

Comment: add the image of the coding which will be helpfull in solving the issue

Comment: My code file is too big. All of the buttons are working fine but this button isn't changing color. I have added `@IBAction` as well as `@IBOutlet` and tried both ways to change the background color of a button but its not working. There are also other buttons which are working fine.

Comment: Please check `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` connections for the button in storyboard, also check if `sender` instance is the same button that you're working on.

Comment: @N4SK everything was connected and working fine just not changing the color and text of button which I figured out the solution and mentioned the solution in answer. Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally after hours of work I figure out the all connections are working and I have to set `tintColor` not a `backgroundColor` to change button color. I have tried changing `tintColor` before but I didn't see the change because `backgroundColor` was overriding it. All this confusion occured because. of two reasons.

1). I imagined that button color is `backgroundColor` but its was actually `tintColor`

2). There are almost three variables in storyboard with same `backgroundColor` as seen in given images which are overriding colors and even color was changing I was unable to see the change. As far as title change is concerned using this line did the trick

`sender.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)`

instead of this line

`sender.titleLabel?.text = "Button"`

[image: First Image]
[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 0):

initialize the button like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnname: UIButton!
```

then in viewdidload or function

```
btnname.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: Already mentioned this thing

Comment: yeah sir but this will be clear as in coding